# Yii2 dropdownList select default option

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am returning cat_id value by GET in url to say that my dropdown list, which Item must be select.
But it's not working.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cat_id')->dropDownList(
ArrayHelper::map(DeviceCats::find()
->where(['is_deleted' => 'no'])->all(),'id','title')
,['options' => [$_GET['cat_id'] => ['selected'=>true]]
, 'prompt' => ' -- Select Category --']) ?>
```

Comment: Refer http://www.saidur-rahman.com/default-selected-value-in-a-dropdownlist-in-yii/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally solved with an unbelievable change. Just changed the first letter of selected to capital ('**selected**' should be '**Selected**').
Here is the code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'cat_id')->dropDownList(
ArrayHelper::map(DeviceCats::find()
->where(['is_deleted' => 'no'])->all(),'id','title')
,['options' => [$_GET['cat_id'] => ['Selected'=>'selected']]
, 'prompt' => ' -- Select Category --']) ?>
```

Answer (score 10):

'Selected' must be written with a capital letter 'S':

```
'options'=>['72'=>['Selected'=>true]]
```

Comment: Why the hell selected must be written with capital S? This must be a bug or something. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that your model has the property cat_id set. Someplace in your controller just do a

```
$model->cat_id = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, 'cat_id');
```

or

```
    $modelArray = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, 'nameofmodel');
    $model->cat_id = $modelArray['cat_id'];
```

If you really want to do it like you did, probably you have to use the name of the model too in there.

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'cat_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(DeviceCats::find()->where(['is_deleted' => 'no'])->all(),'id','title'),['options' => [$_GET['SOMETHIGNHERE']['cat_id'] => ['selected'=>true]], 'prompt' => ' -- Select Category --']) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Mihai.
Actually, I am sure about the existing the value in the array.
Also, I have used var_dump($_GET) and it's on level 1.

Comment: that is my point... it should not be. You are jumping through hoops to get that working and doing it wrong too. Instead you should move the code in the controller. Besides that you are using PHP globals directly and that is a no no.